InvalidUri error when transfering the whole OneNote to blob storage
I am trying to write a python script that will extract all pages within all sections of a OneNote notebook and transfer the content of each page into Azure Blob Storage. The program works for the first hundred or so pages and then abrubtly stops working after reaching section 21 and produces the following error message:
HttpResponseError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[39], line 72
     70 print(p_title)
     71 try:
---> 72     container_client.upload_blob(name=p_title,data='p_content', overwrite=True)
     73 except KeyError as ere:
     74     print(ere)
File .\tester\Lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py:78, in distributed_trace.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper_use_tracer(*args, **kwargs) //tester is my kernel
 76 span_impl_type = settings.tracing_implementation()
     77 if span_impl_type is None:
---> 78     return func(*args, **kwargs)
     80 # Merge span is parameter is set, but only if no explicit parent are passed
     81 if merge_span and not passed_in_parent:

File: .\tester\Lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_container_client.py:1125, in ContainerClient.upload_blob(self, name, data, blob_type, length, metadata, **kwargs)
1123 timeout = kwargs.pop('timeout', None)
   1124 encoding = kwargs.pop('encoding', 'UTF-8')
-> 1125 blob.upload_blob(
   1126     data,
   1127     blob_type=blob_type,
   1128     length=length,
   1129     metadata=metadata,
   1130     timeout=timeout,

...
ErrorCode:InvalidUri
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidUri</Code><Message>The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
RequestId:4fcbf4ad-501e-0059-1d3e-c2ae87000000
Time:2024-06-19T11:46:07.8701879Z</Message></Error>
...

This is the code I wrote:
request_rate = 250

#specify headers that will enter each graphAPI request
_headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + curr_access_token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

def get_pages_within_section(site_id,section_id):
    #specify url of pages within a specific section
    url_pages_within_section = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/onenote/sections/{section_id}/pages"
    response = requests.get(url_pages_within_section, headers=_headers).json()
    return response['value']

def get_page_content(site_id,page_id):
    # specify endpoint (url of a specific page from a specific section)
    url_page = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/onenote/pages/{page_id}/content"
    #call to that page to get its contents
    for i in range(request_rate):
        pass
    page_response = requests.get(url_page,headers=_headers)
    print(page_response)
    #if everything went well
    if page_response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text,'html.parser')
    else: 
        # otherwise retry in the dumbest, easiest way possible
        time.sleep(300)
        page_response = requests.get(url_page,headers=_headers)
        page_response.raise_for_status()
        if page_response.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text,'html.parser')
        else:
            # if you failed again, just give up ;/
            page_title = None
            page_content = None
            return page_title,page_content

    #if this is truthy then go on and give us the good stuff
    if soup.title.string:
        page_title = soup.title.string
        if page_title.endswith('.'):
            page_title = page_title.split('.')[0]
    else:
        #just in case if something STILL goes wrong return the following
        page_title = None
        page_content = None
    
    page_content = page_response.text
    return page_title,page_content


i = 1

#for each section within the notebook
for sec_num, section in enumerate(list_sections['value']):
    #get pages for that section
    print(sec_num)
    section_info = get_pages_within_section(site_id=__site_id,section_id=section['id'])
    if i == 1:
        i=0
        print(section_info)
    #for each page within that section
    for page in section_info:
        #get page title and its .html content
        p_title, p_content = get_page_content(site_id=__site_id,page_id=page['id'])
        #then upload a new blob into our previously established container
        if p_title:
            # container_client.upload_blob(name=p_title,data=p_content, overwrite=True, content_settings = cnt_settings)
            print(p_title)
            try:
                container_client.upload_blob(name=p_title,data='p_content', overwrite=True)
            except KeyError as ere:
                print(ere)

        else:
            print(f'came across an empty one!{p_title}')

I am expecting the program to print out response status codes along with the page title of the retrieved page and obviously to upload correctly into blob storage.


ErrorCode:InvalidUriContent: 
InvalidUriThe requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.RequestId:4fcbf4ad-501e-0059-1d3e-c2ae87000000Time:2024-06-19T11:46:07.8701879Z

The above error is not with code, The error may be invalid path or names or characters provided in the blob parameters.
According to this MS-Document

Ensure that the blob name does not contain invalid characters and does not exceed the allowed length
If hierarchical namespace is not enabled on the storage account, the blob name can't have more than 254 path segments.


Note:
Avoid blob names that end with a dot (.), a forward slash (/), a backslash (), or a sequence or combination of the two. No path segments should end with a dot (.).

In your code, try to modify the page_title like below:
page_title = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_]', '_', page_title)

If page_title is good then change the p_title like below:
if p_title:
     safe_p_title = urllib.parse.quote(p_title, safe='')
     print(safe_p_title)
     container_client.upload_blob(name=safe_p_title, data=p_content, overwrite=True)

Make sure in naming and referencing Containers, Blobs, and Metadata to avoid InvalidUri.
